# Various ways to get month name from inbuilt C library

Tags: c++, c

What are the various ways to get the name of the month corresponding to an integer value [**say 0 for Jan,1 for February ,...,11 for December**] from inbuilt C/C++ library, I am familiar to `strftime`.Any other means to do the same ?

Comment: Why would you need more than one method, and why would the standard library provide more than one method?  That would be remarkably inefficient, and that is not the nature of the standard library which is remarkably terse.

Comment: The std::time_put STL class is another way.  Just harder to use.

Comment: On what platforms? nl_langinfo isn't supported on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const nl_item nl_abmons[12] = {ABMON_1, ABMON_2, ABMON_3, ABMON_4,
                                   ABMON_5, ABMON_6, ABMON_7, ABMON_8,
                                   ABMON_9, ABMON_10, ABMON_11, ABMON_12};
    const nl_item nl_months[12] = {MON_1, MON_2, MON_3, MON_4, MON_5, MON_6,
                                   MON_7, MON_8, MON_9, MON_10, MON_11, MON_12};
    int i;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n",
                i+1, nl_langinfo(nl_abmons[i]), nl_langinfo(nl_months[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ cc months.c
$ LANG=ja_JP.utf8 ./a.out
1        1月    1月
2        2月    2月
3        3月    3月
4        4月    4月
5        5月    5月
6        6月    6月
7        7月    7月
8        8月    8月
9        9月    9月
10      10月    10月
11      11月    11月
12      12月    12月
$ LANG=ru_RU.utf8 ./a.out
1       Янв     Январь
2       Фев     Февраль
3       Мар     Март
4       Апр     Апрель
5       Май     Май
6       Июн     Июнь
7       Июл     Июль
8       Авг     Август
9       Сен     Сентябрь
10      Окт     Октябрь
11      Ноя     Ноябрь
12      Дек     Декабрь
$ LANG=de_DE.utf8 ./a.out
1       Jan     Januar
2       Feb     Februar
3       Mär     März
4       Apr     April
5       Mai     Mai
6       Jun     Juni
7       Jul     Juli
8       Aug     August
9       Sep     September
10      Okt     Oktober
11      Nov     November
12      Dez     Dezember
```

It does so happen in all implementations I know of that `MON_1..MON_12` are sequential, so this could be written `for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) printf("%d %s\n", i+1, nl_langinfo(MON_1+i));` with the same practical effect, but I don't see that guaranteed in documentation anywhere.

Comment: That's nice !! But could we convert it such that it correspond to integer values ? Ofcourse I don't want to build up a big hash map for MON_{1-12} :)

Comment: NB: nl_langinfo isn't supported on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
// For Windows systems, using LCID
LCID lcid = MAKELANGID(LANG_FRENCH,SUBLANG_FRENCH_CANADIAN);
TCHAR szMonth[12][20] = {0};
for (int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
    if ( ::GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1+i, szMonth[i], ARRAY_COUNT(szMonth[i])) )
        szMonth[i][0]=_toupper(szMonth[i][0]); // For better formatting ( French for instance)
}
```

Note : The LCID of target language can be read from the exe resources ( with [VerQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(...,_T("\VarFileInfo\Translation"),...) , or built with [MAKELANGID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro